# failing to link: ABI conflict between functions IN THE SAME FILE

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, abi

I do not understand how this can happen.  In g++ I am getting an error that there is an ABI conflict between two routines defined in the same file, at the same time, under the same ABI directives.  For reasons unknown the linker is searching for the C++11 version of a function, in spite of me being very careful to tell it not to use the C++11 version of absolutely anything, in every last call to g++ in my makefile.

Here is the relevant chunk of makefile - using _D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11ABI=0 before anything is included. All the other .o files are built the same way.

```
project: chrome.o critter.o gene.o loc.o mask.o main.o octree.o rng.o save.o test.o utils.o
    g++ -std=c++17 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11ABI=0 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -lstdc++ -lm -Wall -o project chrome.o critter.o gene.o loc.o mask.o main.o octree.o rng.o save.o test.o utils.o

main.o: main.cpp main.h save.h utils.h gene.h chrome.h critter.h
    g++ -std=c++17  -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11ABI=0 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -lstdc++ -c -Wall -o main.o main.cpp
```

Here is the relevant chunk of source code.

```
// the makesave method returns a string which is to be written to a savefile.
std::string rundata::makesave() const { // save all data
    std::string parmsave = rparms.save2string();
    std::string genesave = genes.makesave();
    std::string chromesave = chromes.makesave();
    std::string crittersave = critters.makesave();
    return("<rundata> "+ parmsave + genesave + chromesave + crittersave + " </rundata>\n");
}


// the saveData method opens and writes the savefile.
void rundata::saveData(){
    FILE *sav = fopen(rparms.savename(), "w");
    if (sav == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Error opening save file to write.\n"); exit(1);}
    std::string outstr = makesave();
    fwrite(outstr.data(), 1, outstr.size(), sav);
    fclose(sav);
}
```

And here's what happens when I run make:

```
albert@juno:~/src/nevermind$ make
g++ -std=c++17  -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11ABI=0 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -lstdc++ -c -Wall -o main.o main.cpp 2>&1 |  head -20
g++ -std=c++17 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11ABI=0 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -lstdc++ -lm -Wall -o nevermind chrome.o critter.o gene.o loc.o mask.o main.o octree.o rng.o save.o test.o utils.o 2>&1 | head -20
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `rundata::saveData()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2ac): undefined reference to `rundata::makesave[abi:cxx11]()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This isn't a call for a wrong-version library function caused by failure to use the macro before including libraries: This is a call to a function defined in the same file, compiled at the same time, with the same ABI directive in place.  And I have an ABI conflict?!

How is this even possible?

Comment: I found troubleshooting in [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html) may be helpful. Actually I found `*.o` targets in your makefile have no source, so maybe you just used some `*.o` files that incompatible with older ABI. As the link shows, you may rebuild `*.o` files with older ABI as well.

Comment: The answer is in your question: `-D...` is an argument for the **C++ preprocessor**. You must specify that when compiling each `.cpp` file into a `.o` file. It does nothing at the linking stage.

Comment: Does specifying it at the linking stage undo the effect of having done it when compiling each and every .o file?  Because I did specify it when compiling each and every .o file.  But even if I had missed one of the .o files, how can this happen in a call between routines in the SAME FILE?  Because that file either is compiled with the correct ABI, and no problem, or isn't, and the problem would show up in calls to routines in files that were.

Comment: Obviously my understanding of the situation is wrong in some way, so don't take my comment above as contradiction in principle.  But I really want to understand how this can happen, so I'm putting my (wrong) understanding of it out there so somebody who knows the truth can correct me.

Comment: @SHP - Can you please say in different words whatever you meant by "*.o targets in your make file have no source?" I gave the makefile line for the only .o file that's being compiled here, and it definitely has a source file - it's the last argument in the call.  This may be a communications issue about me being a little neuro-atypical, so forgive me if the question seems stupid.

Comment: @Edward. I'd like to say that `*.o files` like `chrome.o` or `octree.o` does not seem to be generated from your makefile. "No source" means it has no source file like `chrome.cpp` to generate from.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling c++ code with `g++`, you need to do three things to completely specify the language.

`-std=c++17` tells you what the source code is allowed to look like, or means.

`-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11ABI=0` tells it not to call the library functions whose ABIs are compatible with the ABI that was current for this compiler as of C++11.

`-fabi-version=14` tells it to use the most recent ABI for the machine code it's generating.

It is this last thing that I was missing.  I was leaving it free to decide what binary ABI to use for its output, even though it was compiling with `-std=c++17` for its input.  And for some reason I still do not understand, it made a categorically wrong choice.  But if I command it to use the most recent ABI, it is no longer free to make this choice.

I may never know why the compiler did what it did, but at least I know how to make sure it doesn't any more.